# Is every $(n-1)$-connected $n$-manifold embeddable in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^{n}$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Let $M^n$ be a compact, topological $n$-manifold which is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. If $M^n$ is $(n-1)$-connected (i.e. $\pi_i$ vanishes for $i<n$), does it have to be homeomorphic to the $n$-sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n}$?

Comment: This should hold without the assumption that M is embeddable: Hurewicz shows that M is a simply connected homology sphere, so by the topological Poincaré conjecture it is homeomorphic to $S^n$.

Comment: This question becomes more interesting in the smooth category (diffeomorphic instead of homeomorphic).

Comment: To apply the topological Poincaré conjecture you want M to be homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{S}^n$. Are you saying that a simply connected homology sphere is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{S}^n$? Why?

Comment: @Agelos: this follows from Whiteheads theorem for simply connected CW complexes, as well as the fact there's a degree 1 map from $M$ to $S^n$.

Comment: Why is there a degree 1 map from M to $S^n$?

Comment: @Agelos Take a small ball in your manifold, and collapse its complement to a point.